# Inherit from a class that inherit from a UIVIewcontroller (xamarin and c#)

Tags: c#, ios, inheritance, uiviewcontroller, xamarin

I have a class that inherits from UIViewController:

```
public class A : UIViewController {

  public A():base("A",null){
      //implementation
  }

  //Also it has the ViewDidLoad() and DidReceiveMemoryWarning(), etc.
}
```

Now i have a class B inheriting from A:

```
public class B : A {

  public A():base(){
      //implementation
  }

  //Also it has the ViewDidLoad() and DidReceiveMemoryWarning(), etc.
}
```

Then i create a B class instance:

```
B b = new b();
```

But when the screen appears, it throws

"Failed to find selector setCancelButton: on iOS.B"

So the question is: how can i access items on a class inheriting from UIViewController (item in .xib) from a child class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put an Attribute on each class registering them on Objective-C:

```
[Register("A")]
public class A : UIViewController { }

[Register("B")]
public class B : A { }
```

Comment: Sorry i think i didn't explain the problem clear enough. First, this is C# over Xamarin (not Objective-C). Second, by items i didn't clarify those are items in UI (.xib). Third, i think those Register... are included by Xamarin on the .designer.cs